# Where are virtualized files located in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uac

I can find UAC virtualized folder and file locations in Windows 7 and 8, but can't seem to locate them in Windows 10. Can anybody help?

Comment: For me, they're still in the same place, `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`. Is there anything there for you?

Comment: I have all sorts of stuff there but not the Program Files and Program Files 86 folder :(